# Excessive tag suggestions

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

I'm going through some suggested edits, and this is the eighth or ninth edit like this, suggested by the same person:

[How can we handle errors and exceptions in c like other languages(c++ and Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132048/how-can-we-handle-errors-and-exceptions-in-c-like-other-languagesc-and-java)

[image]

---

[Is there a way to implement unary operators for enum types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457964/is-there-a-way-to-implement-unary-operators-for-enum-types)

[image]

---

[Understanding the implementation of memcpy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187562/understanding-the-implementation-of-memcpy)

[image]

Are these tags necessary? Recommended?

I'm assuming the feedback is going to be something along the lines of "If the question is about that particular language feature, then approve it. Otherwise if it just *uses* the feature, then don't".

It seems most of the requests are being rejected as "too minor". I wanted to hear some feedback on these.

Comment: I suggest you blur out the proposed user's name and photo from your snapshots.

Comment: @R.J What's the point? Everything you do on S.O. is public. And you could easily search for the title and see the edit history.

Comment: I just gave a suggestion. Rest is upto you! :)

Comment: @R.J I mean, I would do it if there was a strong reason to do so. I considered it when I uploaded, it just didn't make sense to me. (Pending further peer pressure).

Comment: Dear god he has a lot of rep from suggested edits.... I too am interested in the answer.

Comment: @OGHaza Which of course is my suspicion for why there are so many suggested re-tags.

Comment: There's a 1,000 rep cap from suggested edits @OGHaza. If you think this is too much then suggest that it gets changed but you can't use it as a negative against people.

Comment: All these tags seem highly relevant so I'm not sure I see the problem

Comment: @RichardTingle Perhaps a lot of them are. Maybe most questions are just insufficiently tagged, but it seemed like some of his suggestions were for what I would consider pointless tags, like `object` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148321/object-assignment-in-c-sharp) or the wrong usage of `inline` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348818/is-it-faster-or-better-to-declare-an-array-inline-in-java), or `loops` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254420/why-does-this-code-give-me-an-infinite-loop).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards, true but it's not that I care how much rep someone receives, it's that I don't like people actively looking to mass edit in the pursuit of rep - those same people would likely still mass edit after hitting the cap anyway in pursuit of badges. I can't think of any way to avoid it, but I don't have to like it. That said the cases in this post all look like ok edits - I know very little about correct tagging practices so I skip all but the obvious rejects in the queue.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with generating your first 1000 reputation from edits, the system is designed to cater for it and it's a good opportunity to go through a lot of content and contribute to the site without actually having a question to ask.