# Review audits for tag suggestions

Tags: discussion, tags, review, suggested-edits, review-audits

Nowadays, there are an [excessive tag suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212566/excessive-tag-suggestions) in Stack Overflow. But, currently we don't have any audits for suggested edits that only change tags.

Why shouldn't we have it?

Share your thoughts.

Comment: I guess it's hard to generate clear-cut invalid tag suggestions

Comment: @JanDvorak what about [tag:clear-cut-invalid-tag]?

Comment: you mean, creating random tags like [tag:asdffdsa]? Hmm... interesting...

Comment: @JanDvorak yes, like that. Really interesting challenge would be to create audits requiring approve to pass. I'd think of something like taking a _known good_ audit item for CV queue with first tag stripped off and presenting audit as a suggestion to add that tag

Comment: @gnat many of your suggestions could easily come up legitimately too minor

Comment: What if we took a tag that was recently blacklisted, faked it into a question and suggested its removal, ideally with a link to a meta page discussing its removal?

Comment: @JanDvorak well it depends on whether audits purpose will be defined to teach reviewers appreciate really legitimate tag edits. Though, if it is preferred to use more straightforward audits, system can introduce couple couple typos and mix "fixes" for these into fake suggestion

Comment: ...and by the way, the typo I (unintentionally:) made [in prior comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212567/review-audits-for-tag-suggestions#comment684179_212567) - `couple couple` suggests a reasonable way to generate mentioned typos - just fake duplication of one of the words and add extra-word removal to audit

Comment: @gnat then it should be valid to reject these as too minor

Comment: @JanDvorak audit suggestion that fixes both tag and typo (introduced over a known good audit item) - how could it be too minor?